# Read file and store values into two arrays, one for each line

Tags: java, arrays, split, bufferedreader

I got this code here:

```
   try{

        FileReader file = new FileReader("/Users/Tda/desktop/ReadFiles/tentares.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);


        String line = null;


        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){


            String[] values = line.split(",");

            grp1 = new int[values.length]; 


            for(int i=0; i<grp1.length; i++){
                try {
                    grp1[i]= Integer.parseInt(values[i]);

                }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }               
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grp1));

        }

        System.out.println("");

        br.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

This is what the file im reading contains.

```
       grp1:80,82,91,100,76,65,85,88,97,55,69,88,75,97,81 
       grp2:72,89,86,85,99,47,79,88,100,76,83,94,84,82,93
```

Right now im storing the values into one int array.
But if i wanted to store each line of values into two arrays?

Thought about using Arrays.CopyOfRange somehow, and copy the values from the int array
into two new arrays.

Comment: Have you tried to add in two arrays. It simple, just proceed you can do.

Comment: You could also use a 2-dimensional array, wherein each 1st level index corresponds to a line and each second level index to a split `int`.

Comment: What about the numbers 80 and 72, whose are the first numbers of each line? They stick together with characters and the ':' and will cause a NumberException. You catch it right, but the numbers won't be stored in your array...

Comment: How could i get the numbers 80 and 72 into the array?

Comment: @user2874051 Try out the stuff in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `while`

```
List<int[]> groups = new ArrayList<>();
```

Before the end of the loop:

```
groups.add(grp1);
```

Afterwards:

```
for (int[] grp : groups) {
    ...
}
```

A `List` is useful for a growing "array".

```
groups.size()     grp1.length
groups.get(3)     grp1[3]
groups.set(3, x)  grp1[3 = x
```

Answer (score 2):

*This answer won't correspond to your question, but will give a hint to my comment under your question post.*

Try this at the beginning of your while loop:

1. Use [String.IndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) to find the first occurence of the char `:` into each line. This will be the beginning index for the second part.
2. Call [String.Substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) from your new beginning index to `line.length`. This will give you the line without the characters and your first numbers aren't lost.